# Vaadin ComboBox setValue not working

Tags: combobox, vaadin

I am having trouble in vaadin combobox after setting a value. here is my code

```
public class ComponentService implements FieldGroupFieldFactory {
/**
     * Create Distributor ComboBox
     */
    public ComboBox createComboBoxDistributor(String caption, boolean required) {
        ComboBox c = new ComboBox(caption);
        BeanItemContainer<Distributor> beans = new BeanItemContainer<Distributor>(Distributor.class);
        beans.addAll(distributorService.find(null));
        c.setContainerDataSource(beans);
        c.setFilteringMode(FilteringMode.CONTAINS);
        c.setRequired(required);
        return c;
    }
}

ComboBox comboDistributor = componentService.createComboBoxDistributor("Disributor", false);
comboDistributor.setValue(this.entity.getCustomer().getDistributor());
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Is there an error or an unexpected behavior?

Comment: guess: your distributor does not provide proper means of equality so the combobox uses object identity and therefor the customers distributor is another object and wont be found in the container thus not selected.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if `distributorService.find(null).contains(this.entity.getCustomer().getDistributor())` as Vaadin uses the equals function of the Bean (Distributor in this case).

Alternatively you can check if `beans.getItemIds().contains(this.entity.getCustomer().getDistributor());` returns true.

If any of the above statements return true, the selection should work.
Maybe the client does not update its content? try `getUI().access( () -> getUI().push());`